# Settimeout function in Firefox does not seem to work

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make the following work?

```
function TimerEvent()
{

      TIMER_OBJ = setTimeout('Ajaxsessioncheck();', '<%=Timer%>');

}
```

I am calling this function in the onload event but it is not calling the Ajaxsessioncheck function when the time has elapsed in Firefox. In IE and Chrome it works fine.

thanks for all for ur time.. i changed the code as sent timer as integer now i have a different problem. In the Ajaxsessioncheck() function i wil call a JSP page from i am not getting Response in Firefox.

Comment: it does work, please show us your code.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?  Do you have a code sample that shows it failing?

Comment: Of course it is. Use it correctly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout . Also: Give us *teh codez*.

Comment: please ask a proper question (give us some code or details)

Comment: If anybody here wants to know why beginners are passing strings into the setTimeout function, and not a proper function reference - it's probably because of stupid W3 Schools `:(`

Comment: @Šime - I see no string in the milliseconds here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp passing a string is perfectly valid. Not best practice, but perfectly valid

Comment: @mplungjan I was referring to the the first argument, not the second. `setTimeout('f();', 1000);` is just ridiculous. People don't understand that they can do `setTimeout(f, 1000);` because they learn from the demos at W3 Schools.

Comment: Actually I did the same for many years (self study using JS 1.0 and 1.1). Most examples on the web use the string until SO taught us otherwise ;)

Comment: Silly title; of course it works. You did something worng.

Answer (score 2):

You've specified `'<%=Timer%>'` as a string (denoted by the single quotes), where it should be an integer, like so: `<%=Timer%>`

You should also specify the first argument as a function reference rather than a string, so your final output would be:

`setTimeout(Ajaxsessioncheck, <%=Timer%>);`

Comment: That has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The callback part, I didn't notice you changed the timeout part.

Comment: This answer would be better if you specified what was wrong; which part you changed to fix the problem, and which part you changed just to make the code "better".

Comment: @Alin: Ah, I see - I thought I was missing something! Yes, I submitted before changing that and then updated immediately (hence no 'edit' on the answer, I presume...)

@Tomalak: Agreed, but lunch was calling - updated now.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't pass the second parameter as string.

```
   TIMER_OBJ = setTimeout('Ajaxsessioncheck();', <%=Timer%>);
```

should work fine. but to be even more correct, you should also avoid passing the first parameter as string, because otherwise is gets evaluated - a hidden execution of `eval` happens, and `eval` is evil. therefore, this is what you want:

```
   TIMER_OBJ = setTimeout(Ajaxsessioncheck, <%=Timer%>);
```

PS. declaring a variable without using keyword `var` causes it to leak to the global scope. I'm not sure if you're aware of this fact.

Comment: @wild A settimeout handle SHOULD be in global scope in my experience unless you want a setter/clearer member

Comment: @mplungjan why? in my experience, in most cases nothing except single namespace should be in the global scope. of course you'll need some methods to access and handle this timer.

Comment: Yes, as I suggested. But that is too OO for most people :) Not all of us are purists ;)

Comment: @nplungjan Nope, the number of global variables should be kept at minimum. There is no reason for the timer to be a global variable.

Comment: @Šime there is no reason in my book to add more functions to handle a single setTimeout on a page. I declare a `var tId=""` in the top of my page when I need one. But yes, you and wildcard are both correct. If I could I would amend the comment to _a setTimeout handler should RARELY/NEVER be in **local** scope_

Comment: @mplungjan Just `var tID;` is fine - there's no need to set its value to an empty string. Also, I don't see why that variable has to be global - even if you need it on a page-level, you can at least put it inside the load/ready handler. There are several hundred global variables in the browsers - by creating new global variables, you risk collisions.

Comment: thanks for all for ur time.. i changed the code as sent timer as integer now i have a different problem. In the Ajaxsessioncheck() function i wil call a JSP page from i am not getting Response in Firefox.

Comment: please ask another question and explain it a bit more (*code code code*)

Comment: I prefer empty string and I do not set such vars in my onload. We all have different ways.

Comment: @mplungjan But why do you prefer `var t = '';` to `var t;`? Habit? Sentimental reasons? If you'd set the timer variable to zero - `var tID = 0;`, I would kind-of understand that (since setTimeout returns an interger ID), but an empty string has nothing to do with timers.

Comment: Yes habit  :)  I feel uncomfortable doing clearTimeout on a null var :) But I will change my habit and declare it as
`var tId=0; // the Šime Vidas var`

Comment: actually, setting it to null or keeping as undefined is most reasonable to me. setTimeout doesn't return int, but an object.

Comment: @wildcard Nope, setTimeout returns a Number value.

Comment: @Sime, it's interesting. It does return Number value in a browser, but in NodeJS it returns Object.

Comment: @mplungjan Then let me assure you that passing `undefined` to `clearTimout` has no effect and won't throw an error. I'm still not sure why `clearTimeout('')` is OK for you and `clearTimeout(undefined)` isn't - both are falsy values and both are invalid timer ID's. If you want to make sure that you only clear the timer if there is an active timer present, I recommend this approach: `if ( tID ) { clearTimeout(tID); }`. Although, as I already said, `clearTimeout(tID);` will work just fine even if `tID` is `undefined`, or `null`, or `''`, or `0`, or any other non-integer value.

Comment: @wildcard How do you know it's an object?

Comment: @Sime,

> x = setTimeout(test, 10)
{ _idleTimeout: 10,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _idlePrev: { repeat: 0, _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular], callback: [Function] },
  _idleNext: { repeat: 0, _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular], callback: [Function] },
  _idleStart: Mon, 28 Mar 2011 14:18:04 GMT }
> typeof x
'object'

Comment: ok, \n formatting is not working here. the '{ ... }' part and 'object' were returned by node.

Comment: @wildcard According to the [HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#timers) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), `setTimeout` returns a Number value. I'm not sure why it returns an object for you. Maybe some NodeJS module defined a custom `setTimout` function which shadows the built-in `setTimout` function ...

Comment: @Sime, AFAIK setTimeout and setInterval are not a part of any ECMA specification - instead, they belong to the host environment. As NodeJS doesn't even provide `window` object, it's clearly using it's own implementation of these methods. I guess I've answered myself:)

Comment: @wildcard Node.js is based on the V8 JavaScript engine. I don't know whether or not V8 defines a setTimeout function, and if yes, what the return value of that function is in V8. Unfortunately, I don't know where to look for this information also - there doesn't seem to be a V8 reference online (and I don't have V8 installed).

Comment: @Sime, as I've found setTimeout definition in http://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/source/browse/trunk/src/lib/juice/time.cc - which is extension to v8 - I think it won't be present in v8 itself. Can't say if it returns Number or Object still, cause it references some external method.

Answer (score 1):

'<%=Timer%>' is a *string* - it should be an *int* in milliseconds.

Almost all questions starting with X does not work in Y comes down to differences in browser implementation. Similar to 
**document.getElementById does not work in firefox** and the element has a name but no ID. Works in IE but not in Fx